# Как в Java сделать фигуру полупрозрачной? Есть ли встроенные методы для этого?

Tags: java, графика, graphics, awt

Как в Java сделать фигуру полупрозрачной? Есть ли встроенные методы для этого?
Например, рисую круг и заливаю его красным цветом. Потом поверх него рисую прямоугольник, больший по размеру и заливаю его, допустим, синим цветом. Необходимо поставить для прямоугольника определенный уровень полупрозрачности для того, чтобы был виден и круг под ним.
Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно или установить цвету прозрачность, или, для более сложных случаев, использовать [`AlphaComposite`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html)

```
public class Alpha {

    static void initUi() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel colorWithAlpha = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
                g.setColor( Color.WHITE );
                g.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );

                g.setColor( Color.RED );
                g.fillOval( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );

                // rgba, a - альфа-канал, непрозрачность
                g.setColor( new Color(0, 0, 255, 128) ); 
                g.fillRect( 0, getHeight()/3, getWidth(), getHeight()/3 );
            }
        };

        JPanel alphaComposite = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                try {
                    g2d.setColor( Color.WHITE );
                    g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );

                    g2d.setColor( Color.RED );
                    g2d.fillOval( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );

                    // композит SrcOver отображает исходное изображение (src,
                    // прямоугольник), поверх целевого изображения, с заданной
                    // в derive( float ) alpha
                    AlphaComposite composite = AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive( 0.5f );
                    g2d.setComposite( composite );
                    g2d.setColor( Color.BLUE );
                    g2d.fillRect( 0, getHeight()/3, getWidth(), getHeight()/3 );
                } finally {
                    g2d.dispose();
                }
            }
        };

        JPanel content = new JPanel( new GridLayout( 1, 2 ) );
        content.add( colorWithAlpha );
        content.add( alphaComposite );

        frame.setContentPane( content );
        frame.setSize( 800, 600 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( Alpha::initUi );

    }
}
```

- [Обучалка от Oracle по композитам](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html)